# An error occurred when updating zabbix from version 5 to version 6

Tags: zabbix

Good afternoon, I took a dump of the database from the main server, deployed a copy of Zabix debian 10, updated to version 5 of zabbix, everything works stably, as soon as I started updating the version to 6, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coKZJ.png)

Zabix had to update Debian to 11 and post gree from 11 to 13, after that the database shows in the zabbix logs that it is not values ​​c_dchecks_1"